# Do I need any article in the following case?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Today we've designed Unforgettable Day campaign.

or

Today we've designed ***the*** Unforgettable Day campaign.

Comment: Yes, "the" is needed.

Comment: You could also use "an" if this is one of many possible campaigns.